# Shopify's 'slate' package not running after installation

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, shopify

**I just installed Shopify's 'Slate' package using npm.**

Terminal shows that the package was added to '/.npm-packages/lib'.
[image]
However, when I attempt to build a new shopify theme using the command 'slate theme newthemename', the command isn't found...
[image]
...even though slate clearly *was* installed.
[image]

Curious to figure out what I'm doing wrong, so any help/advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installation of slate is successful. However, the slate program (`slate/lib/index.js`) is not added to environment variable `PATH`, that's why error `command not found` is reported.

To fix this issue, a simple method is add `slate/lib/index.js` to `PATH` manually. For example, create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin/` and make it point to `slate/lib/index.js`:

```
sudo ln -s /<absolute_path>/@shopify/slate/lib/index.js /usr/local/bin/slate
```

Please note the first parameter of `ln -s` must be absolute path. If relative path is used, Mac OS X (I'm on 10.12.6) won't help to translate it.

Comment: Hey there! Here's the result after following your advice: http://imgur.com/a/lVClz

Comment: @Androbaut Sorry I made a mistake about the `ln` command, the answer has been edited. Please check.

Comment: Here's what terminal reports: http://imgur.com/a/YClNc
Thanks again for the help & sorry to be taking up your time...

Comment: @Androbaut It's weird. It seems you already have `slate` in `/usr/local/bin/` but `/usr/local/bin` is not in PATH...Can you: 1. delete `/usr/local/bin/slate` and try the `ln` command again. 2. run command `echo $PATH` and check whether `/usr/local/bin` in PATH?

Comment: OK, deleted `/usr/local/bin/slate`, ran `ln` command again & `echo $PATH`. `/usr/local/bin` appears to be in PATH: http://imgur.com/Knw2zS7

Comment: @Androbaut According to the screenshot, you used `.../node_modules/@shopify/......` -- there are 3 dots before `/node_modules`, is it a typo? Can you use absolute path instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153086/discussion-between-shaochuancs-and-androbaut).

Answer (score 2):

Please execute the below command from your terminal.

`npm link @shopify/slate`

Basically this command creates a symlink to your package folder, it will check for the global (npm) modules first, and will check for the local modules if there is no match.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Prior to running npm link & out of desperation, I executed 'brew install node' from the directory I'd like to create the new shopify theme in. This added a 'node_modules' folder to said directory. I think this was a mistake... frustrated because I know all I need is a good day or two to dig in and learn the ins and outs of node, homebrew, gulp, etc. but there's a deadline hanging over my head like a guillotine...

Comment: Were you able to overcome the issue?

Comment: Hey David, thanks for following up. I'm currently attempting to add  'slate/lib/index.js' to PATH manually per the advice of another user

Comment: @Androbaut Can you please try executing `npm link @shopify/slate` command?

Comment: Hey there, just tried that, here's the result: http://imgur.com/a/NOLfz

Comment: Thanks for the initial advice, running `sudo ln -s /<absolute_path>/@shopify/slate/lib/index.js /usr/local/bin/slate` ultimately solved my problem